# Reliable file caching

Tags: javascript, css, caching

I'm trying to determine the best way to cache my JavaScript and CSS files.

There are several ways of doing this:

1. Using the `Date`, `Expires` and `Cache-Control` headers
2. Using the `ETag` header
3. Cache forever and change the filename when the file changes
4. Append a querystring to the filename in the HTML with the last mod time or an MD5 of the file contents

I was under the impression that the last method (4) was the most reliable and would result in the fewest unnecessary requests, but my friend just told me that sometimes the querystring method is unreliable and you actually need to change the filename.

Are there any downsides to setting the HTTP headers to cache forever and just using a query-string with the last mod time, or are there scenarios where another method would be more beneficial?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of method 4, but I use the Session Id, on it. So, a user that enters my website will load it once per session (a session usually dies if the visitor keeps inactive for more than 20 minutes or if he closes the browser window).

In Asp.net, I use that syntax:

```
<script src="js/DetalhesCurso.js?<%=Session.SessionID%>"></script>
```

Comment: Why use session ID over last mod time? They'll request the file every time they come back to the site rather than only when it changes.

Comment: It's relatively safe to do so and it's not heavy on the server; you keep yourself comfortable about long-time script caching, something that's always a pain...

Answer (score 1):

Your third method is the most reliable. [Some CDNs/proxies ignore the query string altogether, and just serve the same cached file regardless of the query string value](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/08/23/revving-filenames-dont-use-querystring/).

[Amazon](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/05/amazon-cloudfront-support-for-dynamic-content.html) and [Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff919703.aspx) do support it, but others might not.

Do note that in method #3 you don't *actually* have to update the filename itself. You can just use some URL rewriting to always get that same file. You'll only have to update your HTML.

Comment: So (4) is only unreliable when using a CDN? I thought it was up to the  *browser* to request the file when it thinks its changed? And the browser wouldn't even request it if the Expires header is set correctly?

Comment: @Mark - True, but when you then change the query string and the browser *does* request a new copy, the CDN might serve a cached one. Also, this has nothing to do with whether you personally use a CDN/proxy. It might be some caching down the line, either by the ISP or on the local network or whatever...